# Why does this helper function give me an unbound value error?

Tags: ocaml, nfa

I have a helper funtion which is as follows:

```
let rec helper2 nfa l symb res =
        match l with
        | [] -> res
        | h::t -> res@(transitions nfa.trans symb h) in
                       helper2 nfa t symb res
```

Now when I try compiling it it gives me an unbound value error at the last line saying nfa is unbound value. I am just trying to use the recursive function with the same nfa so I dont know why I keep getting this error. I have encountered this error multiple times in different parts of my code as well.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

What @octachron is telling you is that there's no expression in OCaml that looks like this:

```
a in b
```

But that's what your code seems to be asking for:

```
res@(transitions nfa.trans symb h) in
                   helper2 nfa t symb res
```

It's difficult for us to help any more than this because it's not completely clear what your code is supposed to do. Let's assume that the recursive call to `helper2` is supposed to return a new value for `res` and that you want to use this new value where your current code has `res`. Then something like this might work:

```
let res' = helper2 nfa t symb res in
res' @ transitions nfa.trans symb h
```

There is no expression of the form `expr1 in expr2` but there *is* an expression of the form `let var = expr1 in expr2` as here.

In OCaml (and functional languages in general) you need to think of defining new variables rather than of modifying existing variables. Modification isn't possible for a variable like `res`; it's immutably bound to one specific value. But you can compute a new value and use the new value instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your formatting is lying to you. The right formatting for your function is:

```ml
let rec helper2 nfa l symb res =
  match l with
  | [] -> res
  | h::t -> res@(transitions nfa.trans symb h)
in
helper2 nfa t symb res
```

which is probably not what you wanted.
It may be useful to setup an auto-formatting (or indenting) tool in your workflow.

Comment: Thats not what I want to do. I want to call the recursive function at the second pattern match itself. and Even when I tried this format it still gave me that error

Comment: If you want to call the recursive function, you should write your code accordingly. In the code that you have written the `in` close the definition of the `helper2` function.

Comment: So how do I modify the result list and then call the recursive function on t and the new result?